# Why isn't my highcharts chart getting reset/destroyed properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

In my code I'm initializing the chart like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var chart = null,
defaultOptions = {
chart: etc etc
};


function drawDefaultChart() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(defaultOptions);
}

$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        drawDefaultChart();
    });
});

</script>
```

then in the body I have

```
<a href="#" onclick="drawDefaultChart()">Reset</a>
```

but when you click the link, all it does is redraw the graph with the settings from the previous state... I'm not quite sure what is going on. If I add chart.destroy(); the chart doesn't work at all...

```
function drawDefaultChart() {
    chart.destroy();  //this makes the chart not work at all
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(defaultOptions);
}
```

You can clearly see that I 'm pasing default options to the chart that is suppose to get redrawn.... I don't understand why it uses the old filter settings, i'm about to jump off a bridge, can somebody PLEASE HELP?

my live example is here http://goo.gl/sGu0M

//////// UPDATE

I was able to do it with a lot of blood, sweat, and tears. I ended up putting the data into a php variable on another page (to save real estate), and then calling it using php variables, and then I just call it everytime someone clicks a link. I figured out that in order to redraw the graph, you have to reload ALL the data in each time. The PHP makes this easier in terms of amount of data on the screen.

this was the link that eventually helped me figure it out. http://jsfiddle.net/dane/YUa3R/34/

Comment: `$(function() 
    $(document).ready(function() {` - ready handler in a ready handler? hmmm

Comment: WHERE do you change default options? no where that I can see, so it simply re-executes the same thing...each time you click that link

Comment: shouldn't my initial "defaultOptions" brace set the options as a snapshot?

Comment: I mean, to follow up to your point... i DON'T change the default options... so when you click the button, shouldn't it reset the graph to the ... default options when it was drawn the first time? That is my thinking here.

Comment: I don't understand, are you saying that I have to use a fresh new set of options when I use that function? How can you go about doing this without making the code messy?

Comment: Mark - can you please show me an example of how to change default options as you specify? ... though I still don't quite understand... what exactly would I change the options TO? The default options are already being set, as you can see in my live example here http://goo.gl/sGu0M

Comment: The problem is that Highcharts will add extra options to object you are passing, so for example, when hiding/showing series, your defaultOptions object will contains extra property: `visible:true/false` for each series. Just use copy of that object when passing defaultOptions.

Answer (score 6):

Always it's recommend to refer [API](http://api.highcharts.com/) documentation.

use following snippet to destroy the chart `$('#container').highcharts().destroy();`

[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-destroy/) for a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I know NOTHING about highcharts, but it would seem you need: (from your actual page)

```
function drawDefaultChart() {
$("#container").empty();
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(defaultOptions);
}
```

to be

```
function drawDefaultChart() {
    $("#container").empty().highcharts(defaultOptions);
}
```

OR perhaps:

```
function drawDefaultChart() {
    $("#container").highcharts(defaultOptions);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response Mark, I tried all three but unfortunately none of them made any difference as to the behaviour of the chart

Comment: i swear to god im going to start crying, http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-destroy/ i'm following the official API example here and cannot even get the example to work... nothing happens upon destroy, has "Destroy" been deprecated???? you can see the live code here http://goo.gl/sGu0M

Comment: I was able to figure it out eventually, LATE last night, thank you so much for your help Mark! I put the edit of how I did it in the original post..